# Access dockerized redis from windows host

Tags: docker, redis

For node backend development on windows I am trying to setup redis in a docker container as the redis windows version seems to be buggy for me. I am very new to docker and I am not aware of all the principles coming along with it.

**What I have done so far:**

1. Installed docker
2. Run 'docker pull redis'
3. Run 'docker run --name some-redis -d redis redis-server --appendonly yes' to start the redis container

**The problem:**

I tried connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379 (which used to work when I had redis installed natively on my system), but it is timeouting. I thought that the redis container has it's own ip address and I figured it's ip addres sis 172.17.0.2. Connecting to this ip didn't work either though.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' some-redis
172.17.0.2

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d3b796e9df5c        redis               "docker-entrypoint..."   About an hour ago   Up 8 minutes        6379/tcp            some-redis
```

What am I missing in order to connect from my local machine to redis inside of my container? (My node application is not dockerized)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You miss to expose port. Run redis container with command

`docker run --name some-redis -p6379:6379 -d redis redis-server --appendonly yes`

If `Dockerfile` contains `EXPOSE <some_port>` it means **another containers into same docker network** can connect to this port. Nothing more.

If you want to connect to container from host machine you need say docker about it.

- you can add `-P` option to `docker run` command. In this case docker
  exposes all defined ports to random ports on you local machine.
- Or
  you can  add option `-p<port_on_host_machine>:<port_inside_docker_container>` then you expose certain port.

Comment: Exposing the port is part of the redis image I am using, see: https://store.docker.com/images/redis?tab=description

Comment: Just try it ) Or you can look at `... or via redis-cli` section into your manual.

Comment: Just tried it and now I am actually able to connect to 127.0.1 . Very weird. Can you explain that?

Comment: Documentation on EXPOSE provides some detail: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose EXPOSE tells it to listen, the user has to actually publish it

Comment: Thanks for the very easy to understand explanation @BukharovSergey, that helped me a lot :-).